# Agglomerative Clustering without knowing number of clusters

Tags: clustering, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to perform agglomerative clustering, but I have no idea of number of clusters before hand. But I want that every cluster has at least 40 data points in it. How can I apply this to sklearn.agglomerative clustering? Should I use dendrogram and cut it somehow? I have no idea how to relate dendrogram to this and cutting it out. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is an awesome explanation here, that you may find useful. It has answers and examples on how to select the cut-off from the dendrogram, and code to implement it in python.
https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/

Comment: According to [our answer guide](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there."

Comment: For a concise guide on input parameters used in various clustering algs, check the [scikit-learn overview on clustering methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

Answer (score 1):

A minimum cluster size will not generally be satisfiable in hierarchical clustering. Instead, you have to expect many clusters with just a single point.

ELKI has some fairly interesting techniques to cut a dendrogram. Check the `clustering.hierarchical.extraction` (or so) package. If I remember correctly, some allow you to set a minimum size (but there will be a "noise" cluster with all the leftovers).

Answer (score 1):

If you don t know the number of clusters, i encourage you to look at those density based algorithm : [Mean Shift](https://github.com/beckgael/Mean-Shift-LSH), DBSCAN, OPTICS.
They don t presume of the cluster number and are able to find random shape clusters.